# Draw overlapping areas on one path

Tags: android, android-canvas, porter-duff

I have a `Path` that crosses over itself and I want to change the color of the areas that are gone over more than once. Like below:

[image: desired behavior]

So I set up my paint.

```
    highlighterPaint = new Paint();
    highlighterPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    strokeWidth = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20,
            displayMetrics);
    highlighterPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    highlighterPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN));
    highlighterPaint.setAlpha(200);
    highlighterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    highlighterPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
```

But when I call `canvas.drawPath(mPath1, highlighterPaint)` and `canvas.drawPath(mPath2, highlighterPaint)` I get the below image. There are two Paths in this picture with their endpoints labeled.

[image: actual behavior]

I'm drawing each path onto a `Canvas`.

Separate `Path`s correctly darken their shared area, but a single `Path` does not. How can I achieve an effect similar to the first image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Path` simply cannot do this. Never fear, there is a better way!

The trick is to split the path into many smaller sections and draw each section separately.

In my case, I was creating a path from a series of points (generated from touch input) and drawing quadratic beziers to connect the points. Here is a quick outline:

```
int numPoints = 0;
for (Point p : points) {
    p1X = p2X;
    p1Y = p2Y;
    p2X = p3X;
    p2Y = p3Y;
    p3X = p.x;
    p3Y = p.y;

    numPoints++;
    if (numPoints >= 3) {
        startX = (p1X + p2X) / 2.0f;
        startY = (p1Y + p2Y) / 2.0f;
        controlX = p2X;
        controlY = p2Y;
        endX = (p2X + p3X) / 2.0f;
        endY = (p2Y + p3Y) / 2.0f;
        path.rewind();
        path.moveTo(startX, startY);
        path.quadTo(controlX, controlY, endX, endY);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, it's also a very good idea if you use this method to draw the path into a bitmap that you manage then during your `View.onDraw()` draw your bitmap onto the view.

Comment: what will be p2X , p2Y all this?